# C# Cloud Function (System Packages Included in Cloud Functions not loading)

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, ffmpeg, google-cloud-functions

I am new to cloud functions, and I'm trying to load the FFMPEG system package included in ubuntu (System Packages Included in Cloud Functions  |  Cloud Functions Documentation  |  Google Cloud)

Currently i am trying to load the FFMPEG system package like this:  `Process.Start("ffmpeg",$"-i {temp_input_file} -vn -acodec wav {temp_output_file}");` but i am getting this error

```
An error occurred trying to start process 'ffmpeg' with working directory '/layers/google.dotnet.publish/publish/bin'. No such file or directory
```

I did this with python and it worked fine but i have a requirement to work with C#.

Thanks.

I tried `Process.Start("ffmpeg",$"-i {temp_input_file} -vn -acodec wav {temp_output_file}");`

I need it to convert from MP4 to WAV in c# using google cloud function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a weekend of debugging I solved this issue, which relates to the version of OS the google cloud functions use, Since FFMpeg is not included in Ubuntu 22.04 and .Net 6 (which I was using) runs on Ubuntu 22.04 and .Net 3.1 runs on Ubuntu 18.04 which has FFMpeg, so this how I was able to fix this issue,

Thanks.

[Issue Solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBIQH.jpg)

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the recommendation, as I said earlier I am new to cloud functions and the GCP in general so I did not know I could do this in the console because I thought that I could not install new packages in the cloud OS. Your answer works!

Comment: @john-hanley do this instalation persist between function calls?